# How to draw a web service using UML

Tags: web-services, uml, soa, class-diagram

What's the best and most elegant way to represent a web service interface using a UML class diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is just a diagram to help pass a point so whatever is clear. One option is to use stereotypes put "contract" on the interface and put "web service" on the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) not a [Class Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram).

[Web Service with UML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restemp/)

Comment: This article also [uses a class diagram](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restemp/WS_Respose_Template.gif), as well as a [**"*** solution outline ***"**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restemp/WRST_Outline.gif).  A [Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) is not for showing structure.  These approaches are all based around the **very** old WSDL/SOAP WS models.  Modern RESTful WS APIs just use *documentation* to communicate the service's structure and responses.