# How can I map external interfaces in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are designing a new system and have to document interfaces with outer webservices. I think I should create a map where source is our system and target is outer one.  To do this on attribute level found that "Link to element Feature" can be used. Problem is that this is only visual aid and does not show up  other than diagrams.

So one way is to use source and target role. But is this correct?

Comment: Do you want to document it like http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/ebooks/Modeling%20Service-Oriented%20Architectures.pdf or more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459912/how-to-draw-a-web-service-using-uml or more like http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/soa_and_xml/import_wsdl.html? What exactly do you mean by map external interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced the same problem, and we also considered using "Link to Element Feature". But in the end it felt way too cumbersome and messy.

It might be OK if you only have a few attributes to map, but once you start mapping large flatfiles all the relations start making a big mess on the diagram.

We finally decided to document the mapping in an external excel file. The main reason was that excel provided an overview of the whole mapping in one page whereas in EA you would have to select each attribute to inspect the details.

If you are determined to use "Link to Element Feature" then you might want to take look at the [EA Navigator add-in](http://bellekens.com/ea-navigator/). That is a free and open source add-in I developed that allows you to easily navigate from one linked feature to another in both directions.

Comment: The answer to question "_How can I document..interfaces..in EA..?_" in the form "_You can't, use Excel instead_" is little bit strange. Can you backup your recommendation by some official guideline from Sparx Systems?

Comment: @xmojmr I'm not saying you can't, I'm recommending not to. You can do a whole lot in EA (project management, testing, emails) but that doesn't mean that you should. I tend to use only EA for what it is good at: UML modelling.

Comment: Thank you. After long considerations we decided too to use excel. As for now there is no other straightforward solution. By the way +1 on your excel importer, it has been a great help to us. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your assumption. The linked element feature is stored in the table t_diagramlinks and thus only valid in the context of a diagram. But EA manages this link to be consistent in all diagrams by checking for an existing link.

You can read t_diagramlinks with `Repository.SQLQuery` and check the Geometry column (see chap. 2.5 of my Inside book for details).

Comment: Where is the "my Inside book"?

Comment: Oh, I'm posting the link on the Sparx forum below my answers. Here it is: http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html

Answer (score 1):

In strict UML terms, this notation is not correct. "Link to element feature" is an EA-specific function, while the UML standard states that relationships go between elements.

The fact that a connector is linked to a feature is difficult (though not impossible) to pull out of the database and API for use in scripts and searches, and EA's built-in model transform scripting language does not support it.

Visually, diagrams with large numbers of connectors tend to get very messy very quickly and you can't control the spacing between attributes in a diagram very well (you can set a larger font for a class, but that's it). You can control the order of the attributes, which can help -- but if you want the order to match the one in the actual data representation you probably won't be able to avoid a lot of crossed connectors.

Furthermore, mappings of this kind aren't usually straightforward attribute-to-attribute. An attribute in format X can be derived from several attributes in format Y, there might be a complex algorithm involved and the mappings may well work differently in the two directions.

So, as usual, the answer is "it's really up to you." If you don't care about following UML strictly, if your mappings are simple, if you only want to show roughly "these attributes map to those", if you're prepared to accept a higher degree of manual maintenance of your diargams and if you're not planning on using MDA transformation then you can use this function. Otherwise I'd advise against it.

Comment: "An attribute in format X can be derived from several attributes in format Y"
That's a good point and I understand you would not recomend to use my original idea. But what is the alternative besides excel in ea.